# Can we send Desktop notification or email notification using Google Sheet?

Tags: notifications, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet for employees to update Mileage reading everyday manually (individual sheets). It has a **Date** Column and a **Mileage** Column. What I want is if they don't update the mileage column on a particular date before 10.00 AM, they have to get notification by mail or message or desktop.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

How about this google sheets addon? Looks like you'll need to have their e-mail included in the sheet as well though.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/add-reminders/heaonogefgelopikfimfllmifhbohdbn?hl=en

edit: if that isn't comprehensive enough, there is a pretty good write up here:
http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/automating-google-spreadsheets-email-reminders/

Comment: i want send notification if cell is blank after 10 AM but this different right  do u have any idea to use this for my requirement

Comment: Read through the without scarcasm blog and see how you go.